# Nest observables RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, nested, observable

I have two interfaces:

```
interface Project {
...
CurrentProjectPhase : number
...
}
```

and

```
interface Phase {
PhaseId : number
Projects$ : Observable<Project[]>
...
}
```

both are returned from individual http services as oberservables.

I'm trying to sort the projects via their currentPhase attribute into the phases. Before I did this via subscribing to both and attaching a filtered subset of all project elements to the phase:

```
this.phaseService.loadAllPhases().subscribe((ph) => {
      this.projectService.loadAllProjects().subscribe((pj) => {
        ph.forEach((p : Phase) => {
          p.Projects = pj.filter(project => project.CurrentProjectPhase === p.Id);
        });
        this.phases = ph;
        this.projects = pj;
      })
    })
```

In that case the Phase had a Projects: Project[] instead of the Observable.

I would like to refactor this to stay as observables as long as possible. I've tried this:

```
this.projects$ = this.projectService.getProjects();

    this.phases$ = this.phaseService.getPhases().pipe(
      tap(phases => phases.map(phase=> 
        phase.Projects$ = this.projects$?.pipe(
          map(projects=> projects.filter(project => project.CurrentProjectPhase == phase.Id)))
      ))
    )
```

But (ofcourse) it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `this.projects = this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe();` wouldn't have worked since that assigns the subscription object to `this.projects`. And is `projects.filter(` in the first supposed to say `this.projects`?

Comment: I have edited the question because @Carcigenicate was right

Comment: it looks like you need a database join, not a custom uniting code

Comment: Yes @Andrei that would be my last resort to request an api change here. Currently I use pagination and filters on the getProjects() before sorting them to phases. This allows to have foe. 10 projects per each phase.

Comment: I think the relevant part is in projectService: it is is responsibility of building the objects and it's there that you have to build the objects. How is the API built? With which parameters? The number and nesting of observables is dictated by your API and should match the API's granularity. It's not something you get to decide on the client side. E.g. are all projects for a phase returned together? Do you query the phases as a list and then you have a separate call for each phase? Or what? And remember that if you have pagination on the server side, the backend MUST handle also the sorting.

Comment: _"I would like to refactor this to stay as observables as long as possible."_ - could you please explain why? Currentlich I don't see a reason for it and it makes it hard to write a good answer. If you load _all_ phases and _all_ projects anyway, why do you want to stick to `Projects$ : Observable<Project[]>` instead of `Projects$ : Project[]`? The only reason I can see, would be lazy loading, which your API (or at least the client side service) doesn't seem to support.

Comment: I get both lists from an httpclients api call. I use them to draw like a kanban board. While the phases are pretty much constant, as the user can add phases from the addmin menue. Before sorting the projects to the phases i map them to the queryparams to make use of pagination and user filters on the projects. I use d&d to change the phase of the projects and resort them to different phases. My understanding of RXjs is, if I have a (pseudo code:) Phase{Projects[].pipe(filter(Phase.Id))} thing that the updates to Projects could be handled in the OnPush strategy with a Redux like Store concept.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine them:

```
const filtered = this.projectService.getProjects().pipe(
    combineLatestWith(this.phaseService.getPhases()),
    map(([projects, phases]) => {
        phases.forEach((phase) => {
            phase.projects = projects.filter(project => project.CurrentProjectPhase == phase.Id)
        });
        return phases;
    }),
)
```

Or something like that. My brain's a bit tired, so this might be a tad off.

Now you can subscribe to `filtered` to get the results whenever you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a forkJoin if you are using HTTP calls that will both complete once it is returned.  I am not sure why you would like to keep Projects as an observable in the Phases interface but maybe the code below will work:

```
const projects$ = this.projectService.getProjects();
const phases$ = this.phaseService.getPhases();
const combined$: Observable<Phase[]> = forkJoin([projects$, phases$]).pipe(
  map(([projects, phases]) => {
    return phases.map(phase => {
      const phaseProjects = projects.filter(project => project.CurrentProjectPhase === phase.PhaseId);
      return {...phase, Projects$: of(phaseProjects)};
    })
  })
);
```